# When creating new DOM elements via jQuery, why are empty Style attributes added to them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome-devtools

I am creating and appending `<li>` elements to the DOM via jQuery whenever the user clicks a specific button. However, once they are added to the DOM, they appear as `<li style=""></li>`, in comparison to `<li></li>`. Why is this happening?

I understand that, visually, this doesn't cause a problem. However, it does cause a problem when trying to find a specific element's index in an array.

Function that adds the `<li>` element:

```js
function addNewTask(input) {
  let userInput;

  userInput = input;

  let task = '<li><span class="text-task">' + userInput + '</span><span class="delete-task">x</span></li>';

  //parent = $('.task-list');
  $('.task-list').append(task).children(':last').hide().fadeIn(250);
  arr.push(task);
  localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(arr));
  console.log(arr);
}
```

Function that attempts to find array index of DOM element (currently not working as intended - it can not find the index by the specified value):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.delete-task', function () { // We use 'on' as the element is dynamically added
        console.log("'Delete' button pressed");
        var $self = $(this);


        var index = this.parentElement.outerHTML;

        var findIndex = arr.indexOf(index);

        arr.splice(findIndex, 1);

        $self.parent().fadeOut(250, function() {
            console.log($self.parent().html());

            $self.remove(); // Dynamically remove the DOM element from the list
            localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(arr));


            console.log(localStorage.getItem('items'));

        });
    });
});
```

HTML Expected Output:

```
<li><span class="text-task">' + userInput + '</span><span class="delete-task">x</span></li>
```

HTML Actual Output:

```
<li style=""><span class="text-task">' + userInput + '</span><span class="delete-task">x</span></li>
```

**Update (Problem Solved!):**
I was able to solve the problem by removing the `style` attribute once the `.hide()` and `.fadeIn()` jQuery methods had finished executing.

Modified code:

```
function addNewTask(input) {
    let userInput;

    userInput = input;

    let task = '<li><span class="text-task">' + userInput + '</span><span class="delete-task">x</span></li>';
    arr.push(task);

    //parent = $('.task-list');
    $('.task-list').append(task).children(':last').hide().fadeIn(250, function() {
        console.log(this);
        $(this).removeAttr('style');

        localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(arr));
        console.log(arr);
    });

}
```

Comment: Maybe because `.hide()` and `.fadeIn()` add and remove styles

Comment: _“However, it does cause a problem when trying to find a specific element's index in an array.”_ - why/how? You are not actually comparing _HTML code_ for such purposes …?

Comment: Originally your question was simply a request for clarification. Your edit now implies this is an X/Y question as the `style` attribute somehow affects other logic, when it should not. As such, please add the code to the question which demonstrates the issue finding an element's index in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by your use of `hide().fadeIn(250)`. Those methods set inline `display` and `opacity` CSS rules on the affected element. Once the transition completes the rules are removed, but the empty `style` attribute remains.

You can see this happening in the below snippet if you inspect the existing `li` element before clicking the button to add a new `li`:

```js
function addNewTask(input) {
  let task = '<li><span class="text-task">' + input + '</span><span class="delete-task">x</span></li>';
  $('.task-list').append(task).children(':last').hide().fadeIn(250);
}

$('button').click(function() {
  addNewTask('foobar');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="task-list">
  <li>Foo</li>
</ul>

<button>Add</button>
```

If you wanted to remove the orphaned `style` attribute (even though it does no harm), you could call `removeAttr()` in the callback of `fadeIn()`:

```js
function addNewTask(input) {
  let task = '<li><span class="text-task">' + input + '</span><span class="delete-task">x</span></li>';
  $('.task-list').append(task).children(':last').hide().fadeIn(250, function() {
    $(this).removeAttr('style');
  });
}

$('button').click(function() {
  addNewTask('foobar');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="task-list">
  <li>Foo</li>
</ul>

<button>Add</button>
```

Comment: This has seemed to have solved my problem. I was unaware that those methods left behind an empty `style` attribute once they had finished executing. Thank you so much!